# Deportation order issued in Ireland. What about travelling to other EU countries?

Tags: deportation

I recently received an unjust / unfair deportation order in Ireland after my EU treaty rights case was rejected and I filed a humanitarian appeal then. In reply to that humanitarian appeal, they sent a rejection along with a deportation order and asked me to leave the country within 30 days. I left within 15 days of the serving of deportation order. (They gave me temp visas twice while my case was under process and I lived in Ireland for 4+ years). I'm still emailing the irish authorities from my home country now (non EU) , to revoke that unfair/ unjust deportation order. That's a different story. 
Coming back to the questions, so no criminal record/ no penalties/ no detention any where in the world ( i have lived in UK as well by the way) and received this deportation order. So questions are , Ireland being a European country and a deportation order issued there. How long is the ban in Ireland and am I banned from entering other European countries too? 
If yes then how long is the ban for. 
If not, then do I have to disclose this Irish deportation order thing, while applying for any sort of visa for some different EU country. 
And do they share this deportation record with other European countries..

---

I never deceived any country's immigration system. They did some factual errors while dealing with my straight forward application. And replied with a rejection (first my EU treaty rights application was refused after giving me two temporary visas and then I filed the humanitarian appeal, which was rejected as well. They took 4 years in all this process. My mistake was, i should have taken the authorities to court instead of filing a humanitarian appeal because my case was very straight forward and strong ) On rejection of humanitarian appeal a deportation order was issued. My questions were about the number of years ban in Ireland and is there any ban in other EU countries due to this deportation order. E.g Germany, do I have to disclose it to them plus plus any ban, duration etc. If anyone can advise me on this please. I'd be grateful.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with '**my EU treaty rights**' as a non-EU citizen? At some point you will be asked about any rejections or deportations which must be answered truthfully.

Comment: My brother is an EU citizen and I applied a for a residence permit on his behalf as a family member. That's what comes in EU treaty rights

Comment: The German guidelines state that in general only a parent, spouse and children are considered family. One major exception for others is when the EU citizen is responsible for the care in case of severe health problems of that member.

Comment: Siblings do come in immediate family members according to EU treaty rights rules and its same in all European conutries including Germany . And yes there are various conditions of being dependant, health conditions and that includes financially dependant as well.

Comment: I have found court rulings that state otherwise as a general rule (only as dependent of the mother of the EU Brother) . I would suggest asking a question in the Law stack exchange. **Under what conditions is a Brother eligible as Family member accourding to §3 (2) (1 and 2) FreizügG/EU**

Comment: Well you have taken the discussion to a different direction. The EU dependant form I filled in Ireland, it had an option of siblings, so that's understood that siblings were under EU treaty Right's qualified family  members category plus that wasn't my question. My questions were regarding the depprtaion related ban in other EU countries etc.

Answer (score 2):

Both Ireland and the UK participate in the [Schengen Information System](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-information-system_en), so you should assume that most European countries will be aware of your deportation order. This will make it difficult for you to get a visa in those countries.

The UK also shares information with the [Five Eyes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_Eyes) countries: USA, Canada, Australia and New Zealand.

There may be other data sharing arrangements in place.

You should disclose details on any immigration form that asks for them. This alone might be grounds for refusal, but if you don't, and the country to which you are applying already knows about your immigration history, you can expect serious consequences. Attempting to deceive the UK authorities carries a ten year ban, for example, and even after that time it's likely that obtaining a visa will be difficult.

I don't know the duration of any formal ban you might have received in Ireland, but that's largely academic: you won't get a visa there any time soon.

Comment: You’ve linked the page about the visa information system, but in any case, Ireland doesn’t participate in SIS. As you note OP should disclose their visa refusal but I don’t think there’s currently a mechanism that this information would be shared with any country other than then UK.

Comment: Thanks Jeffry. Do you have any info on, if there's any ban on the rest of Eu countries, disclosure policy etc

Comment: @Xee No, as Redd says, your immigration problems in Ireland can be taken into account by Schengen nations, but it does not result in an automatic ban.

Comment: -1 Ireland is neither participating in SIS nor part of Five Eyes. If you think the UK would be allowed to pass information received from Ireland (in relation to the CTA?) on to the Five Eyes countries, please provide some good references.

Comment: SIS is in operation in 30 European countries, including 26 EU Member States (only Ireland and Cyprus are not yet connected to SIS) and 4 Schengen Associated Countries (Switzerland, Norway, Liechtenstein and Iceland). Oh can check on this link https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/schengen-information-system_en